# How to get only Hour and Minute of JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jspinner

I have a JSpinner. When i use`spinner.getValue()`it gives me `Sun Mar 24 01:11:41 PDT 2013`
but i want to have only `Hour and Minute in 24 hour format`

```
Date date = new Date();
        SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.MINUTE);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
        JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm a");
        spinner.setEditor(de);
        if ( spinner.getEditor() instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor ) 
        {
                  JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = ( JSpinner.DefaultEditor ) spinner.getEditor();
                  editor.getTextField().setEnabled( true );
                  editor.getTextField().setEditable( false );
        }

        System.out.println("Spinner:      "+spinner.getValue());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extracting the meat from @mKorbel's answer:

System.out prints the value object uing its toString method, if you want to print it formatted you need to use a Formatter, f.i. the one used by the editor in your code:

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.MINUTE);

JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm a");
de.getTextField().setEditable( false );
spinner.setEditor(de);

System.out.println("Spinner:      "+de.getFormat().format(spinner.getValue()));
```

Comment: that's because you configured the format to show it :-) Either configure it to show 24h or use a separate format (if you want it to differ from the formating of the spinner.

Comment: I use "HH:mm" for 24 hour mode. ;-)
spinnerHours.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinnerHours, "HH:mm"));

Answer (score 5):

- have to use SimpleDateFormat for Formatter

[image]

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TimeZoneSpinners {

    private final String[] zones = {"Asia/Tokyo", "Asia/Hong_Kong",
        "Asia/Calcutta", "Europe/Paris", "Europe/London",
        "America/New_York", "America/Los_Angeles"
    };
    private final JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[zones.length];
    private final SimpleDateFormat[] formats = new SimpleDateFormat[zones.length];
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private SpinnerDateModel model;
    private SimpleDateFormat format;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void makeUI() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setValue(date);
        spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Date date = (Date) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    labels[i].setText(formats[i].format(date));
                }
            }
        });
        format = ((JSpinner.DateEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getFormat();
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[0]));
        format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        format.applyPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(zones.length, 2, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            formats[i].setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zones[i]));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(zones[i]);
            labels[i] = new JLabel(formats[i].format(date));
            labels[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(labels[i]);
        }
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        frame.add(spinner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimeZoneSpinners().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hiding the important stuff in tons of (concededly nice :-) clutter again? Reminder: optimally, answer-code is as SSCCE as question-code

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertTo12Hour(String Time){ //20:00:00
   String input = Time;
  //Format of the date defined in the input String
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  //Desired format: 24 hour format: Change the pattern as per the need
  DateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
  Date date = null;
  String output = null;
  try {
    date= df.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    //Changing the format of date and storing it in String
    output = outputformat.format(date);
    return output;  //8:00:00
```

}